# Does the per activity cost count each data factory individually

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are setting up a data factory to help with our global failover scenario. The Pipeline copies data from our SQL server located on premise into Azure Table Storage.

We are using Data Factory V2 and have set up the [CI/CD pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment) as described in the ADF documentation.

Therefore, our dev and test instances only copy data from the Sql to one region, but our production needs to copy data to multiple regions.  My thought to simplify things would be to have one Factory per region that will only copy data to that region (so that production and dev can share the exact same pipelines).

However, this will mean that we will have multiple pipelines and all of them will have a rather low usage. There are only 3 activities that run once a day, so we will only have 90 activities per month. Looking at the [data factory pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/), you are charged for every 1,000 activities.

My question is, since each of these factories will have less than 1,000 activities, will we be charged the minimum of $1.50 for each factory or will the pricing just charge us once since all of them together will still be less than 1,000 activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! The pricing is calculated per Data Factory instance and not per pipeline. You can have as many pipelines in a single Data Factory instance. You will be charged based on the number of activity runs within a Data Factory instance.

In your case, since you are planning on having multiple Data Factory instances, you will be billed multiple times. Eg- If you have 3 data factories(may or may not be across different regions) and each ADF has 90 activity runs a month, **you will be charged 3x$1.5 = $4.5.**

For an accurate estimation of pricing, please refer :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/

Hope this helps!